# FriendsOfCake's TokenAuthenticate login() and token generation

Tags: cakephp, authentication, token

I can't find any example of how to use FriendsOfCake's `TokenAuthenticate` plugin. I want to know if I have to create the token myself or if it creates it automatically, and also what would be the code inside `UsersController::login()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the token yourself. As well, the `login()` action is the same as any other login action would be.